# tar to stdout: missing input files without affecting PIPESTATUS

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, tar

I have a folder with this content (the subfolders and file names are fixed and cannot change):

```
# ls
data/ config/ myfile
```

I need to create a tar archive to **stdout** to process it with `dd` in a Bash script; suppose for example in this way for the sake of simplicity:

```
# /bin/tar -cz data config myfile 2>/dev/null | /bin/dd of=backup.tar 2>/dev/null
```

Immediately after this instruction I check the variable `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` for 0 to know that `tar` did its work successfully.

The problem is that `myfile` is **optional** for me, and if it's missing my `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` becomes 2 even though I don't want to consider it an error. So how can I instruct `tar` to ignore missing input files? I would prefer a one-line statement, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an option to change the `tar` call:

```
test -e myfile && myfile=myfile || myfile=
/bin/tar -cz data config $myfile 2>/dev/null |
```

Answer (score 3):

> So how can I instruct tar to ignore missing input files?

It's really simple: just use the `--ignore-failed-read` flag on your `tar` command:

**$**`/bin/tar -cz --ignore-failed-read data config myfile 2>/dev/null | /bin/dd of=backup.tar 2>/dev/null`

**$** `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

```
> 0
```

BTW: Note that the answer of *Hauke Laging* is more cumbersome, but `tar` only returns 0 if it's all ok, or if the only file missing is `myfile`... with this, `tar` returns 0 if it's all ok, or even when any file is missing.

---

With this:

`/bin/tar -cz --ignore-failed-read data config myfile | /bin/dd of=backup.tar 2>/dev/null`

(note that I'm not redirecting `stderr` of `tar` to `/dev/null`) if `myfile` doesn't exist, `tar` returns `0` (if there is no other errors, of course) and you get this on `stderr`: `/bin/tar: myfile: Warning: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`

`tar` manual says:

> ‘--ignore-failed-read’
>   Do not exit with nonzero on unreadable files or directories.
>   This option has effect only during creation. It instructs tar to treat
>   as mild conditions any missing or unreadable files (directories). Such failures
>   don’t affect the program exit code, and the corresponding diagnostic
>   messages are marked as warnings, not errors. These warnings can be suppressed
>   using the ‘--warning=failed-read’ option

but, alas, `--warning=failed-read` suppress all warnings about read-errors: in your case, suppress warnings about a file that doesn't exist, but also suppress warning about *I/O errors*, for example... is far from optimal; apparently, `tar` doesn't have a flag to say it: *hey, suppress failed-read warning only if the file doesn't exist*, so, may be, this resolve your problem:

`/bin/tar -cz --ignore-failed-read data config myfile 2> >(grep -v 'No such file or directory' 1>&2) | /bin/dd of=backup.tar 2>/dev/null`

this: `>( ... )` is [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

this way, your `tail` command doesn't change its return number if the file doesn't exist, you don't get warning messages about missing files, and you get warning messages about any other read error.

---

### this>

I can't help thinking that none of this solutions are really good, so, I came up with this:

```
/bin/tar -cz -T <(\ls -A -1) 2>/dev/null | /bin/dd of=backup.tar 2>/dev/null
```

with this, your are sending to `tar` only the files that really exists at the time of command execution: you don't need to worry about their names, or even which file exists or not: you always execute the same command (no matter what), scales perfectly if you have 1 file missing, or *n* files missing, and you don't miss any errors.

(note the *backslash* if front of `ls` command: this way, you prevent any `ls` alias, thus, its output is more reliable)

Comment: But what happens if there are really some errors during the read operation in the **data** or **config** folders? I would like to ignore **not-found** errors but not actual I/O errors.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `--ignore-failed-read` but if there are some files inside `config/` for example that the current user doesn't have permission to read this command returns 0: `# tar cz --ignore-failed-read data config myfile | /bin/dd of=backup.tar
tar: config/config.txt: Warning: Cannot open: Permission denied
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
# echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
0` and this is wrong for me! The process substitution is a bit too much complex too, so I think I'll stick with Hauke's solution.

Comment: I think that none of the previous solutions are good enough: check my last update